# How can I tell Firefox to access intranet

Tags: firefox, lan, intranet

At my job, we have a lot of sites on our intranet. How can I tell Firefox to access the intranet sites?

I keep getting this:

> The requested item could not be loaded by the proxy.
>
> Proxy server is unable to locate the
>   server: myintranet. The server does
>   not have a DNS entry. Check the server
>   name in the Location (URL) and try
>   again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the network setting dialog box, where you define the proxy that firefox will you, you can specify which websites will bypass the proxy server.  In here you will need to specify all of the intranet sites that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

**Tools** -> **Options**

then

icon **Advanced** -> tab **Network** -> **Settings...**

and write in textbox **No Proxy for:**  10.4.* (for example) depending on IP range of your intranet

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to disable proxy for intranet domain. You can do this near the proxy settings, by mentioning "No Proxy for" your intranet domain.